# Android Custom ScrollView containing LinearLayout with Custom Views

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having lots of problems, both with scrolling, and with picking up touch signals in the correct places.

Basically the application is:

```
ViewPager ->
Fragment ->
ScrollView -> 
LinearLayout -> 
Lots of dynamically added customer View objects
```

The fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/transaction_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_new_transaction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/AddNewTransaction" />

<com.company.application.TransactionScroller
    android:id="@+id/transaction_scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <com.company.application.TransactionGroup
        android:id="@+id/transaction_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </com.company.application.TransactionGroup>

</com.company.application.TransactionScroller>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where the TransactionScroller is the ScrollView, the TransactionGroup is the LinearLayout.
The view object is custom drawn, and does the following:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec )
{
    // Try for a width based on our minimum
    setMeasuredDimension( width, height ) ;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event )
{
   Toast.makeText( getContext(), "Grid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show() ;

   return true ;
}

public void draw( Canvas canvas )
{
   if( tmpBmp.isRecycled() || 
       tmpBmp.getWidth()!=canvas.getWidth() ||
       tmpBmp.getHeight()!=canvas.getHeight() )
    {
        tmpBmp.recycle();
        tmpBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 
                                      Config.ARGB_8888 ) ;
        c.setBitmap( tmpBmp ) ;
    }

    //clear previous drawings
    c.drawColor( Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR ) ;

    // Draw the background
    c.drawRect( spacing, top, width - spacing , bottom, newpaint ) ;

    // Draw the lines
   for( Line line : lineList )
   {  
      c.drawLine( line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2, paint ) ;
   }

   canvas.drawBitmap( tmpBmp, 0, 0, null ) ;

   canvas.drawText( String.valueOf( amount ), left, top + ( bottom - top ) /2 , paint);

   canvas.drawBitmap( 
      ( ( BitmapDrawable )MainActivity.iconList[ index ].getDrawable() ).getBitmap(),
      left + MainActivity.iconList[ index ].getWidth(),
      top + ( bottom - top ) /2, paint ) ;
}
```

1) Firstly, I am trying to capture touch and drag events in the custom View object. But I have only been able to capture the events in the ScrollView, only the Down event in the LinearLayout, and nothing in the custom View.

In the ScrolView:

```
setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener()
                       {   
                          @Override
                          public boolean onTouch( View view, MotionEvent event )
                          {
                             // Only called when touched outside the ScrollView

                             if( event.getAction() ==
                                 android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
                             {
                                Toast.makeText( getContext(),
                                                "S_Down",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show() ;

                                return false ;
                             }
                             else if( event.getAction() ==
                                      android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
                             {
                                Toast.makeText( getContext(),
                                                "S_Up",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show() ;

                                return false ;
                             }

                             return false;
                          }
                       } ) ;
```

Which both get called in the ScrollView.
But the same thing in the LinearLayout, only the Down event gets captured
And in the custom view, nothing is captured.
I have tried setting focusable, clickable etc.

Any ideas?

2) Secondly, The ScrollView is not scrolling when it only has my custom View objects in it. But it does when filled with something else e.g. Buttons.
As you can see above, I am using onMeasure(), and I have tried hardcoding these values to no avail.

Thanks in advance.
Jack